# Measure performance of ASP.NET SQL session state provider

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, session-state

We have a very large three-tier .NET 4.0 web application (ASP.NET, WCF, SQL Server 2008 R2) with some performance issues I'm trying to diagnose.  The ASP.NET tier uses the SQL session state provider, and there is reasonably extensive use of session state.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="..." cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

I'm trying to figure out how much time it takes to load and save the session to the database. Note that this is different than using SQL profiler or other database means to measure time on that tier; I want to measure **total time taken from the ASP.NET tier.**  I.e. that would include session object serialization/deserialization, wire time, and SQL save/load time.

I am pretty experienced developer (since the early 80's), and I have Googled the web for *hours* now -- there are tons of articles contrasting session state approaches and general performance concepts etc, but I can find nothing on how to actually measure this total time for the SQL session state provider.  I initially thought of using an HttpModule to hook events and use a stopwatch, but there doesn't appear to be a clean path to this. (I would settle for an approach that's *reasonably* accurate to few percent...)

Any ideas/suggestions are much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try to add some diagnostics code using `Trace` and then just turn on tracing? This way you could diagnose selected pages very thoroughly.

Comment: Where would you add Trace statements?

Comment: In your code, as many as possible so that you can then analyze exact times at when traces where hit.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just alter your session timeout to seconds, and then to a lower and lower amount, until it does not load and save the session?

Comment: Thanks for the thought... Problem is that session state typically is going to build as users hit more pages, do more operations etc.  It will be important to actually measure state provider performance across the app, not just hit a low-threshold timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The managed stack can be profiled in the VS profiler. See:

- [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)
- [How to: Profile a Web Site or Web Application Using the Performance Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx)
- [Analyzing Application Performance by Using Profiling Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx)

For low level stuff use Xperf, see [Two Minute Drill: Introduction to XPerf](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/06/27/an-intro-to-xperf.aspx)

For the SQL Server side there are many methodologies for performance troubleshooting, like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). For specific statement duration/IO cost you can use profiler trace, see [Scenarios for Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190793%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Now for a very *specific* and *invasive* way in your case you can use Performance Counters. Not the stock kind, but create your own. See [Using XSLT to generate Performance Counters](http://rusanu.com/2009/04/11/using-xslt-to-generate-performance-counters-code/) for an ease way to geenrate the plumbing needed to augment your app with its own perf counters, then hook up your code with performance tracing. Use the standard perofrmance counters tool chain ([logman.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490956.aspx), [perfmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx)) to capture and analyze.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to profile the app and look at where the time is spent deep in the bowels of ASP.NET. You will be able to quickly spot session-related activity by class and method name.

Perfview is fine for this. It has a sampling profiler which means that it will give you accurate, unskewed profiling information. But it can't tell you how many seconds were spent in what method. All it tells you are percentages.

I'd spin up a load test against an empty page and let perfview run for 30s.

dottrace is a simple profiler that also shows you the amount of CPU time spent per call, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to create a page that doesn't really do anything other than perhaps load/store the session state variables. From there you can set up a coded UI test that accesses the page a number of times and builds a statistical estimate for the variability and distribution involved in load times for the page.

WCAT (Web Capacity Analysis Tool) could also be used to see how performance changes under load...